# Shell_NotifyIcon() and an invisible window

Tags: c, winapi, shell, tray

I'd like to use Shell_NotifyIcon() to add an icon to the system tray but I do not want to have a visible window in my application. That's why I'm passing a handle to a message-only window to Shell_NotifyIcon(). The window has been created like that:

```
hTrayWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, CLASSNAME, "tray_dummy", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, NULL, HINSTANCE, NULL);
```

CLASSNAME points to the name of my class that I've registered using RegisterClassEx() and HINSTANCE is the handle of my instance.

Now the problem is: The tray icon is added but the WindowProc() of my class is never called. If I use a normal top-level window instead, everything is working fine.

Is there no way to create a tray icon without a top-level window? I've seen apps having a tray icon without a top level window so it must be possible somehow. But why does it not work with a HWND_MESSAGE window?

Thanks!

Comment: If you end up needing to, you can just not pass `WS_VISIBLE` into the style flags for the normal window.

Comment: So there is no way to use a HWND_MESSAGE window for it? It has to be a real window, just without the WS_VISIBLE flag?

Comment: I'm not sure whether a message-only works or not, but that's one solution if it doesn't. It's working out fine for me as I speak (the difference being that mine might be shown in the future).

Comment: Ok, AFAICS HWND_MESSAGE windows don't work...

Comment: Is that thread running a normal message loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, sorry, it was my fault. The reason why it didn't work was that I called CreateWindowEx() from a different thread. When I use the main thread it is working fine.